# Redirect after clicking Share Button on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, share

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect users to a different page in a Page Tab Application similar to [this one](https://www.facebook.com/cawineclub?sk=app_260001524093453)

Comment: I think [FB.Event.subscribe()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) is what you are looking for. - `Attaches a handler to an event and invokes your callback when the event fires.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and set the `redirect_uri` parameter – `The URL to redirect to after the user clicks a button on the dialog.`.

With the following Javascript code you can do that:

```
    FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

    function postToFeed() {

      // calling the API ...
      var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'URL_TO_SHARE',
        picture: 'SHARING_PICTURE',
        name: 'SHARING_TITLE',
        caption: 'SHARING_CAPTION',
        description: 'SHARING_DESCRIPTION',
        redirect_uri: 'URL_TO_REDIRECT_AFTER_ACTION'
      };

      function callback(response) {
        // Some callback action ...
      }

      FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }
```

Then you bind `postToFeed` function to click event of a button or link.